# Javascript/dingbats: counting the number of ✔'s in a string

Tags: javascript, unicode, string-matching, dingbats

I am trying to count the checkmarks in a given string. my string may be:

`var myString = "one ✔ two ✔ three ✔"`

I have tried using `myString.match(/✔/g) || []).length;`, but this is returning `0` (I believe that happens because ✔ is a dingbat symbol).

I know the unicode for "✔" is [2714](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%9C%94), can I use this in my expression?

Comment: What you provided here seems to work fine – https://jsfiddle.net/06o1vnu9/. I'd check the file encodings for your scripts, ensure they match. Otherwise, the character code used to save `✔` may not be the same between them.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks for putting that together. you're probably right about the encodings, but luckily I found a safer solution (answered my own question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem:
I used the "unicode escape sequence" `\u` with the 2714 unicode:

`.match(/\u2714/g) || []).length;`

The problem was likely due to a character encoding issue (see the comments on my question), but this solution seems to be a safe choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with doing a string match with unicode. The match method returns an array of matched elements. In order to count the total you then need the total number of elements in that array. I believe the code you are looking for is:

```
myString.match(/✔/g).length
```

Comment: Note: `.match()` will return `null` if no matches are found. The `|| []` is to ensure an array is always given since you can't read the `.length` of `null`.